# Parameterize $3x^2 + 4xy + 3y^2 = x+3y$

Tags: calculus, parametrization

I am calculating the curve that is formed by the graph between the function $$f(x,y)=3x^2+4xy+y^2$$ and the plane $$z=x+3y$$ 
Then I'm left with the equation $3x^2+4xy+y^2=x+3y$ that I want to parameterize but I'm stuck

Comment: You need to put `$` signs round math expressions to get them formatted appropriately.  Here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I assume you mean the intersection of the plane with the **graph** of the function, i.e., the set of points $(x, y, z)$ with $z = 3x^2 + 4xy + y^2$. In that case, the set of relevant points are those for which the $z$-values are equal, i.e., $$x+3y = 3x^2 + 4xy + y^2.$$ That's the equation of an ellipse in the plane, but it's not centered at the origin, and it's somewhat rotated. Can you find its center? Can you find its axes? (You can add your work by clicking "edit" just under your question.) Note in particular that it's NOT the ellipse defined by $3x^2 + 4xy + y^2 = 0$!

Comment: Indeed, the only real solution to $3x^2+4xy+y^2=0$ is $x=0$, $y=0$. That doesn’t make for much of an ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

put x=r cos A, y= r sin A.
now when you put it you get a relation giving r in terms of angle A , find range of r.

Answer (score 0):

You can write if $$xy\neq 0$$ $$3\frac{x}{y}+4+\frac{y}{x}=0$$ and now substitute $$t=\frac{x}{y}$$

Comment: In the head line you will find $$3x^2+4xy+3y^2=0$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The equation is that of a conic and more precisely an ellipse. You can center and reduce it to the form

$$\lambda_0 x^2+\lambda_1 y^2=c$$ where the lambdas are the Eigenvalues of the matrix of quadratic coefficients. You will find that the Eigenvalues are $1,5$ and Eigenvectors are $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ so that the centered equation reads

$$5(\cos t+\sin t)^2+(\cos t-\sin t)^2=c.$$

Hence the requested parametric equation reads

$$x=\sqrt5(\cos t+\sin t)+a,\\y=\cos t-\sin t+b$$ where the constants $a,b$ that can be found by plugging in the initial equation.

Comment: Tank you Yves, these constants a and b would then be found by plugging x and y into $x+3y=3x^2 + 4xy....$ I assume but would that not give an weird equation with two/three unknowns and turn even more weird?

Comment: @Calle: trust me.

Answer (score 0):

As you and maverick said, taking $$x=r\cos(\theta)$$ $$y=r\sin(\theta)$$ and knowing $x^2+y^2=r^2$ you can give a parametrization of this curve.

$$3r^2\cos^2(\theta)+4r^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)+r^2\sin^2(\theta)=r\cos(\theta)+3r\sin(\theta)$$

$$ r^2(1+2\cos^2(\theta)+4\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))=r(\cos(\theta)+3\sin(\theta))$$
$$ r=\frac{\cos(\theta)+3\sin(\theta)}{1+2\cos^2(\theta)+4\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}$$

Hence you can parametrize your curve as:

$$ r(\theta)=\frac{\cos(\theta)+3\sin(\theta)}{1+2\cos^2(\theta)+4\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}$$

Remark: I do not know if this parametrization will be useful in your case, but it is a parametrization. Now, you need to define the range of $r$ related to the range of $\theta$ you have.